# An HashMap (or ArrayList) that contains different Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, hashmap

For a certain situation, I want to make a `HashMap` where the keys are Fragments and the values are Integers. However, every different Fragment has a different type and is not simply of the type `Fragment`. So the following (which is what I initially tried) doesn't work:

```
HashMap<Fragment, Integer> hmap = new HashMap<>();
hmap.put(new ExampleFragment(), 5);
hmap.put(new AnotherFragment(), 2);
```

Now this won't work of course, since `ExampleFragment` and `AnotherFragment` are not of the correct type to be put in the `HashMap`. 
EDIT: I get the following error in AndroidStudio: `Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 'com.example.sword.rpg.ExampleFragment', required: 'android.app.Fragment'`

Now my question is: how do I store different SubClasses of `Fragment` in the same `HashMap` (or `ArrayList` for that matter) and is this even possible?

I do have a workaround for my specific situation, but it is not as neat as this one would have been. So I'm still curious.

EDIT: I indeed mixed up `Fragment` and `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, thanks :)

Comment: Maybe you should use HashMap<Integer,Fragment> hmap, 
its <Key, Value>

Comment: Not sure why you are trying to achieve but you can just do `HashMap<String, Integer>`  and `hmap.put("ExampleFragment", 5);`

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi that is indeed my workaround. But when picking a random Fragment from this HashMap, this requires some extra logic with an if-statement (or switch case) for every individual Fragment. This feels less neat, and also makes it less friendly to add more Fragments.

Comment: You can store subclasses, however if you have new methods in your subclasses, that don't override the super `Fragment` class you won't be able to use them, unless you explicitly down cast, which could lead to `ClassCastException` if you cast incorrectly.  The same applies to `FragmentManager::getFragmentbyId` - which just has an internal `Map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your question, *it should work*, as this does, so is it possible you mixed up your "fragment" types?  There's a few in typical android namespace (e.g. android.app.Fragment vs android.support.v4.app.Fragment):

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class TestHashMap {

      private HashMap<Fragment, Integer> test = new HashMap<>();

      public static class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {
          public ExampleFragment() { super(); }
          public String toString() { return "ExampleFragment[hash:"+hashCode()+"]"; }
          public void someOtherMethod() {}
      }

      public static class AnotherFragment extends Fragment {
          public AnotherFragment() { super(); }
          public String toString() { return "AnotherFragment[hash:"+hashCode()+"]"; }
      }

      public void test() {
          test.put(new ExampleFragment(),1);
          test.put(new AnotherFragment(),2);
          Log.d("TestHashMap","size = "+test.size());
          Log.d("TestHashMap",test.toString());
      }
  }
```

Which produces:

```
D/TestHashMap: size = 2
D/TestHashMap: {AnotherFragment[hash:230309272]=2, ExampleFragment[hash:5536635]=1}
```

Comment: Hm, that's interesting. When I try that, I get the following error in Android Studio: ```'com.example.sword.rpg.ExampleFragment', required: 'android.app.Fragment'```. Could this be because of the declaration of my fragment?

Comment: Yes, that tells me in a vague sort of way that your "ExampleFragment" is not the same type as that in your HashMap declaration.  Again, be careful of just using "Fragment" - so verify your fully qualified names in imports.  (In my own test, I changed ExampleFragment to a 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment' leaving everything else the same and reproduce the same error as you mentioned - so it sounds as though you are mixing Fragment references.  Use whichever Fragment parent type you want; they just all need to be the same parent type.

Comment: I indeed mixed up ```Fragment``` and ```android.support.v4.app.Fragment```, thanks :)